# fabs vs. fabsl, should I ever have to type fabsl in my source?

Tags: c, c99, xcode7-beta5

I'm rewriting some Mac code that embeds a freeware library originally written in C. The compiler is complaining that since I'm using `long double`, I should use `fabsl` rather than `fabs`. So I went and changed them.

However, reading [a few pages](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) on the topic it seems that there should be no difference, that ever since C99, there is a type generic macro that inserts the correct call based on type.

So perhaps I am using the wrong dialect?

Does anyone know what the Compiler Default is in xcode7, and whether it has the generic macro?

Comment: The macro is defined in another header?! `Defined in header <tgmath.h>`

Comment: Are you `#include`ing `<tgmath.h>` ?

Comment: I am not, it looks like the C code incs math.h. Is there anything I need to know before adding this, or is this really super-generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic macro is defined in `<tgmath.h>`, so you need to `#include it`, as shown in the following snippet:

```
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long double ld = 3.14;
  double d = 3.14;
  float f = 3.14f;
  printf("%Lf %lf, %f\n",fabs(ld), fabs(d), fabs(f));
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles flawlessly with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra a.c -oa -std=c99
```

Comment: Works great, after a few imports. There's no downside to this, the code in question is purely the generics?

Comment: Apart from relying on c99, I guess not.

Comment: And I'm sure this is *purely* coincidental, but as a side effect of #importing these I noticed and changed a few #includes too. And now the app builds about ten times as fast. Sweet!